# Return model with environment variables if no rows in Database

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, environment-variables

I have a table `merchants` in my project, and manager can move site to another merchant in admin panel. In one time, there can be only one active merchant (On activate merchant - I have code, which update all other merchants to `is_active=0`. But there can be situation, when someone delete all merchants, so I want to get it from `.env` file. Is my code elegant for this action? If not - how can I improve this?

```
/**
 * @return self
 */
public static function getActiveMerchant()
{
    $merchant = (new self())->where('is_active', 1)->first();

    if (!$merchant) {
        $merchant = new self();
        $merchant->login_id = config('merchant.LOGIN_ID');
        $merchant->public_client_key = config('merchant.PUBLIC_CLIENT_KEY');
        LOG::warning('There is no one active merchant in the DB');
    }

    return $merchant;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would simply return `false` or `null` for situation where no active merchant =)

Comment: @ankabot Why? I don't want to stop app in this case, I can work with `.env` file. My table is just extended configuration)))

Comment: When there is no merchent, you are making one from config. as far as I understand. If that is your target, then it is ok as of my knowledge (you know, I'm no oracle).

Comment: But in this case, the `$merchant` variable is holding an object which is not really coming from the database. Wouldn't it cause a problem?

Comment: @RazinAbid yes, that is my target. I have main merchant in `.env` file, and just extend it in my DB. The main question was: Is it ok, if I return fake object in production? I think it is ok, because I store a warning, and will fix it very fast without stopping a project))

Comment: Actually if I'm not wrong, a merchant is the very top level (or parent). So to start a production, you must insert a parent. You could do that using laravel seeding or manual entry or as you did with your code. But make sure, you make it yourself, not by your visitors. Otherwise they will be confused. Because they don't know the config data.

Comment: Sure I made seed, and the active merchant can set only in adminUI. The code is just cover case - all merchants removed by manager.